# MySQL SUM all values from table then echo

Tags: mysql

```
Table - Messages
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| msg_id | message | uid_fk | ip | created | uploads|
|  554  Blah....    35     ..  1355000068   0   |
|  555  Blah....    34     ..  1355002587   0   |
|  553  Blah....    34     ..  1354990968   0   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I'm trying to do is get uid_fk and sum it all up, and then be able to echo it using php.
The uid_fk is the user uid in another table called users with some other data. I'm not sure at all how to sum it both together by getting their specific ID's.

I started with this but I'm pretty new with MySQL databases.

```
    public function Total_Posts($uid){
        $query          = mysql_query("SELECT uid_fk, sum(count) as sum from messages group by uid_fk");
        $num            = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $return $num;
}
```

---

```
UPDATE: Working Version

    public function Total_Posts($uid){
        $messages       = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE uid_fk='$uid'");
        $numrows        = mysql_num_rows($messages);
        return $numrows;
    }

    <?php 
        $Total_Posts        = $Wall->Total_Posts($uid,$total);
    ?>

    <?php echo $Total_Posts; ?>

Seems to work great, thank you for all the help.
```

Comment: something like `SELECT    SUM(value) FROM      myTable` ??

Comment: @NullPointer, if you could look bellow I posted on Justins answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get all the elements you need:

```
$messages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE uid_fk='$uid'");
```

then sum:

```
$sum=0;
while ($message = mysql_fetch_array($messages)){
    $sum += $message['uid_fk'];
}
```

Comment: Gingy Mcdonal, public function Total_Posts($uid){ $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE uid_fk='$uid'"); } And in...

PHP

<?php $sum=0;
while ($message = mysql_fetch_array($messages)){
    $sum += $message['uid_fk'];
} ?>
does that look right? Sorry, I'm new but I'll keep searching! Thank you for the quick answer

Comment: Justin, thank you for the help! very much so, but it's only returning a 0, not counting anything from database.

Comment: it may not be grabbing any rows from the database. try looking at the number of rows:
$numresults = mysql_num_rows($messages);

Comment: Still continues to return constant 0. Tried adding the while inside the MySQL as well and didn't work. What I currently have..http://pastebin.com/z1PN8pxG

Comment: I got it working, thank you very much for the help. I will post here just in case someone else may need it in the future.

Comment: Answer accepted:) maybe you can help with another one of my question! if possible!